# Display 3 maps equally

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

How can I get a 33% equal split for 3 map panes - I keep getting the middle map being smaller than the left and right ones for some reason.  Theres no header or footer - just 3 maps.  If anyone can help that would be great.

[image]

Code below:

```
<body class="claro">
    <div id="mainWindow"  data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.BorderContainer">
        <div id="map0" data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.ContentPane"  data-dojo-props="region:'left'"></div>
        <div id="map1" data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.ContentPane" data-dojo-props="region:'center'"></div>
        <div id="map2" data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.ContentPane" data-dojo-props="region:'right'"></div>      
    </div>
</body>

#mainWindow {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

 #map0, #map2 {
    width: 33%;
 }

#map0, #map1, #map2 {
    margin: 5px;
    border:solid 4px #224a54;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
}
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with the api or anything, but I notice width isn't explicitly defined for #map1 - what if it were? Since it isn't, my guess would be the borders and margins for all three are being taken out of its intended 33%. I also saw [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16742986/setting-div-map-height-and-width-to-100) on SO, which might be related and talks about parent containers overriding the map class.

Comment: It is correct to not set a width for the center pane in a border container: it's supposed to work it out.  However, i wonder in you are right about it being due to the margin/border.  Vidar, try setting the content pane margins and borders to 0.  If it then looks even I'd suggest nesting a separate div in each to be the map divs and to apply the margins and borders to.

Comment: check the .dijitContentPane:padding as well.

Comment: Thanks chaps - It would appear that is all to do with the css/margins gutters etc and the claro css or whatever theme you choose.  Thanks for your help guys.